# Highlight functions in Visual Studio Code like NetBeans

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

What I need to have is demonstrated in the following two screen shots, where first one from NetBeans IDE 8.2 and the second from VSCode 1.17.2.

[image]

[image]

I typically wants to have the white highlight,*on the left*, line appears in the NetBeans IDE to be found, or something like it, in VSCode.

I have tried the following setting:

```
"editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
```

I also tried to search for any plugins about folding and code highlight but I could not able to determine which one is suitable to perform this visual effect on code highlighting.

Comment: I seem to remember an extension to variously color the indent guides based on level.  But I can't find it now.  You have the indent guides enabled.  You can brighten them with the     "editorIndentGuide.background": "#fffa",
option in the   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
but hat will change all indent guides not just the function level, which may be too distracting for you.

Comment: @Mark I think that the feature in the NetBeans that I mean, is not indent guide.

Comment: No, I agree.  But if there is no similar functionality or extension, I only suggest the indent guide (with customized alpha/coloring) as a possible option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no visual indicator in the gutter portion of the editor in VSCode.
That was requested in [`Microsoft/vscode` issue 25132](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25132) or [issue 19690](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19690), closed in favor of [issue 60670](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60670) and [PR 77363](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/77363): "Add folding from end of region", which was never merged.

For now, VSCode 1.42 (Q1 2020) proposes "[**Folded region highlighting**](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/12321bdd72b061e9020574b3173b19cfa4ff278f/release-notes/v1_42.md#folded-region-highlighting)"

> Folded code regions are now easier to discover with the addition of a background highlight.
>
> The feature is controlled by the setting **`editor.foldingHighlight`** and the color can be customized with the color **`editor.foldBackground`**.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editor.foldBackground": "#355000"
}
```

That means those functions (which are foldable) are easier to spot.

From there:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> once on the folding indicator to first fold the inner ranges.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> again (when all inner ranges are already folded) will fold the parent.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> again unfolds all.

[image: Folding with shift + click -- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/images/1_42/folding-shift-click.gif]

Answer (score 0):

useful with --> Ctrl + Shift + \ Jump to matching bracket